# How to correctly wrap JSX elements and display JSON depending on selection

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I'm developing a university administration website with React that can be displayed in different languages. So far I have developed the Login page which looks like this:

[image: University administration login page]

At this point, I'm trying to display the website in the selected language(EU, ES, EN) but I'm getting a *Module build failed* error:

[image]

I don't really understand why is giving this error as I think the JSX/html tags are correctly wrapped (note that I'm using **Babel**), please see the code:

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { fetchPopularRepos } from '../utils/api'

function LanguagesNav ({ selected, onUpdateLanguage}) {
  const languages = ['EU', 'ES', 'EN']

  return (
    <div >
      <h1 className='center-text header-lg'>
        GAUR 2.0
      </h1>
      <ul className='flex-center'>
        {languages.map((language) => (
          <li key={language}>
            <button
              className='btn-clear nav-link'
              style={language === selected ? { color: 'rgb(187, 46, 31)' } : null }
              onClick={() => onUpdateLanguage(language)}>
              {language}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

LanguagesNav.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onUpdateLanguage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function LoginForm ({ repos, selectedLanguage }) {
  return (
    <form className='column player'>
      {(repos, selectedLanguage) => {
        var lang = { username, password, login }
        switch (selectedLanguage) {
          case 0:
            selectedLanguage = "EU";
            lang  = repos[0]
            break;
          case 1:
            selectedLanguage = "ES";
            lang = repos[1]
            break;
          case 2:
            selectedLanguage = "EN";
            lang = repos[2]
            break;
        }

        return (
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='username'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder={lang.username}
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='password'
              id='password'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder={lang.password}
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <button
              className='btn dark-btn'
              type='submit'
            >
              {lang.login}
            </button>
          </div>
        )
      }}
    </form>
  )
}

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'EU',
      repos: null,
      error: null
    }

    this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this)
    this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage)
  }
  updateLanguage (selectedLanguage) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage,
      error: null,
      repos: null
    })

    fetchPopularRepos(selectedLanguage)
      .then((repos) => this.setState({
          repos,
          error: null,
      }))
      .catch(() => {
        console.warn('Error fetching repos: ', error)

        this.setState({
          error: 'There was an error fetching the repositories.'
        })
      })
  }
  isLoading() {
    return this.state.repos === null && this.state.error === null
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedLanguage, repos, error } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <LanguagesNav
          selected={selectedLanguage}
          onUpdateLanguage={this.updateLanguage}
        />
        {this.isLoading() && <p>LOADING...</p>}
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        <LoginForm repos={repos, selectedLanguage} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}
```

The JSON file where I am retrieving the data from:

**languagesdata.js**

```
{
  "languages": [
    {
      "language": "EU",
      "terms": {
        "username": "Erabiltzailea",
        "password": "Pasahitza",
        "welcome": "Sartu GAUR 2.0ra",
        "login": "Sartu"
      }
    },
    {
      "language": "ES",
      "terms": {
        "username": "Usuario",
        "password": "Contraseña",
        "welcome": "Entra a GAUR 2.0",
        "login": "Entrar"
      }
    },
    {
      "language": "EN",
      "terms": {
        "password": "Password",
        "username": "Username",
        "welcome": "Log into GAUR 2.0",
        "login": "Log in"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using an api:

**api.js**

```
export function fetchPopularRepos () {
  const endpoint = 'app/languagesdata.json'

  return fetch(endpoint)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data.languages) {
        throw new Error(data.message)
      }

      return data.languages
    })
}
```

- What's the real reason for the error?
- What's the correct way to display the JSON data depending on a selection with React?

Comment: Thanks for your comment but the question is already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of this,

```
return (
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <input
      type='text'
      id='username'
      className='input-light'
      placeholder={lang.username}
      autoComplete='off'
    />
  </div>
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <input
      type='password'
      id='password'
      className='input-light'
      placeholder={lang.password}
      autoComplete='off'
    />
  </div>
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <button
      className='btn dark-btn'
      type='submit'
    >
      {lang.login}
    </button>
  </div>
)
```

You are returning multiple element's here. Just wrap this in `Fragment` (`<></>`)

```
return (
  <>
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <input
      type='text'
      id='username'
      className='input-light'
      placeholder={lang.username}
      autoComplete='off'
    />
  </div>
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <input
      type='password'
      id='password'
      className='input-light'
      placeholder={lang.password}
      autoComplete='off'
    />
  </div>
  <div className='row player-inputs'>
    <button
      className='btn dark-btn'
      type='submit'
    >
      {lang.login}
    </button>
  </div>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions must return a single DOM element or fragment.

Take a deeper look at what you are returning here

```js
function LoginForm ({ repos, selectedLanguage }) {
//...
        return (
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='username'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder={lang.username}
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <input
              type='password'
              id='password'
              className='input-light'
              placeholder={lang.password}
              autoComplete='off'
            />
          </div>
          <div className='row player-inputs'>
            <button
              className='btn dark-btn'
              type='submit'
            >
              {lang.login}
            </button>
          </div>
        )
      }}
    //...
```

You can either wrap everything into another element or use `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` (or `<></>`).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap what you're returning in `render()` in a `<React.Fragment>` tag.

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div className='row player-inputs'>
      <input
        type='text'
        id='username'
        className='input-light'
        placeholder={lang.username}
        autoComplete='off'/>
    </div>
    <div className='row player-inputs'>
      <input
        type='password'
        id='password'
        className='input-light'
        placeholder={lang.password}
        autoComplete='off'/>
    </div>
    <div className='row player-inputs'>
      <button
        className='btn dark-btn'
        type='submit'>
        {lang.login}
      </button>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

It's like the error message says: "adjacent tags must be wrapped in a [parent] tag".

Answer (score 1):

Error here:

```
return (
 <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='text'
          id='username'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.username}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='password'
          id='password'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.password}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      ...
```

You should to wrap it to one tag like `<div>`

For example:

```
    return (
<div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='text'
          id='username'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.username}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='password'
          id='password'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.password}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <button
          className='btn dark-btn'
          type='submit'
        >
          {lang.login}
        </button>
      </div>
</div>
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your answer is valid, however, I think it's better to wrap it with <React.Fragment> tag as other answers suggest.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is really the best solution than my because it eliminates the need to add redundant <div>

Answer (score 1):

> What's the real reason for the error?

The component is returning multiple JSX elements. But not enclosed in a single parent JSX element. So, use [React.Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) as the error suggests.

```
return (
  <> // shorthand syntax of React.Fragment
    {children}
  </>
);
```

> What's the correct way to display the JSON data depending on a selection with React?

As far as I have checked, you are correctly following how React's [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) states.

The state (i.e `selectedLanguage`) is stored in the parent component and passed to the `<LoginForm/>`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question. Regarding the answer to the second question, correct me if I'm wrong but I think mapping doesn't work for what I want to do, as I need to pass the selected language and based on the selected language the JSON item.

Answer (score 1):

I made your code working as expected, please run and let me know your feedback

Changes

1. wrapped elements return React.Fragment
2. getSelectedLang introduced new method to handle selectedLang instead of doing in LoginForm
3. LoginForm changed into a member inside class
4. injected response directly instead of making request to fetch the data

See the code - https://repl.it/repls/NaturalFarDifferences

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";
//import { fetchPopularRepos } from '../utils/api'

function LanguagesNav({ selected, onUpdateLanguage }) {
  const languages = ["EU", "ES", "EN"];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="center-text header-lg">GAUR 2.0</h1>
      <ul className="flex-center">
        {languages.map(language => (
          <li key={language}>
            <button
              className="btn-clear nav-link"
              style={
                language === selected ? { color: "rgb(187, 46, 31)" } : null
              }
              onClick={() => onUpdateLanguage(language)}
            >
              {language}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

LanguagesNav.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onUpdateLanguage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};



export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: "EU",
      repos: null,
      error: null
    };

    this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this);
    this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this);
    this.LoginForm = this.LoginForm.bind(this);
  }
  getSelectedLang  = (repos, selectedLanguage) => {

        console.log('repos', repos);
          console.log('selectedLanguage', selectedLanguage);
        var lang = "";
        switch (selectedLanguage) {
          case "EU":
            selectedLanguage = "EU";
            lang = repos && repos[0];
            break;
          case "ES":
            selectedLanguage = "ES";
            lang = repos && repos[1];
            break;
          case "EN":
            selectedLanguage = "EN";
            lang = repos && repos[2];
            break; 
            default: 
            break;
        }

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row player-inputs">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="username"
                className="input-light"
                placeholder={lang &&lang.terms.username}
                autoComplete="off"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="row player-inputs">
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                className="input-light"
                placeholder={lang &&lang.terms.password}
                autoComplete="off"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="row player-inputs">
              <button className="btn dark-btn" type="submit">
                {lang && lang.terms.login}
              </button>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        );

  }
  LoginForm = (repos, selectedLanguage) => {
   // let { repos, selectedLanguage } = data;

  return (
    <form className="column player">
      {this.getSelectedLang(repos, selectedLanguage)}
    </form>
  );
}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage);
   // console.log("heoocds");
  }
  updateLanguage = (selectedLanguage) => {
    //console.log(selectedLanguage);
   // console.log("heoocds");

    let obj = 
        [{
          language: "EU",
          terms: {
            username: "Erabiltzailea",
            password: "Pasahitza",
            welcome: "Sartu GAUR 2.0ra",
            login: "Sartu"
          }
        },
        {
          language: "ES",
          terms: {
            username: "Usuario",
            password: "Contraseña",
            welcome: "Entra a GAUR 2.0",
            login: "Entrar"
          }
        },
        {
          language: "EN",
          terms: {
            password: "Password",
            username: "Username",
            welcome: "Log into GAUR 2.0",
            login: "Log in"
          }
        } ]
        this.setState({
          selectedLanguage,
          error: null,
          repos: obj
        });
    };


    // fetchPopularRepos(selectedLanguage)
    //   .then((repos) => this.setState({
    //       repos,
    //       error: null,
    //   }))
    //   .catch(() => {
    //     console.warn('Error fetching repos: ', error)

    //     this.setState({
    //       error: 'There was an error fetching the repositories.'
    //     })
    //   })

  isLoading = () => {
    return this.state.repos === null && this.state.error === null;
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedLanguage, repos, error } = this.state;
    // console.log(repos);
    // console.log(selectedLanguage)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <LanguagesNav
          selected={selectedLanguage}
          onUpdateLanguage={this.updateLanguage}
        />
        {this.isLoading() && <p>LOADING...</p>}
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}
        {this.LoginForm(repos, selectedLanguage)}

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, even though your solution might work, I don't consider it valid, as you've unstructured the whole code and put the JSON data in an object. Please see my answer as I have managed to develop a solution that does what I wanted while keeping the code nice.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem on my own. I wasn't passing props correctly as I was trying to receive 2 props in the *LoginForm* function when I was passing just 1 and I wasn't checking whether repos was null:

```
<LoginForm repos={repos, selectedLanguage} />
```

Solution:

```
{repos && <LoginForm repos={repos} selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage} />}
```

I managed to solve this asking another question: [How to pass an array as props in React without being converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57705819/5464406)

And then I have developed a logic in the *LoginForm* function in order to display the language that is selected.

**COMPLETE SOLUTION:**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { fetchPopularRepos } from '../utils/api'

function LanguagesNav ({ selected, onUpdateLanguage}) {
  const languages = ['EU', 'ES', 'EN']

  return (
    <div >
      <h1 className='center-text header-lg'>
        GAUR 2.0
      </h1>
      <ul className='flex-center'>
        {languages.map((language) => (
          <li key={language}>
            <button
              className='btn-clear nav-link'
              style={language === selected ? { color: 'rgb(187, 46, 31)' } : null }
              onClick={() => onUpdateLanguage(language)}>
              {language}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

LanguagesNav.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onUpdateLanguage: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function LoginForm ({ repos, selectedLanguage }) {
  var lang = {}
  switch (selectedLanguage) {
    case "EU":
      selectedLanguage = "EU";
      lang  = repos[0].terms;
      break;
    case "ES":
      selectedLanguage = "ES";
      lang = repos[1].terms;
      break;
    case "EN":
      selectedLanguage = "EN";
      lang = repos[2].terms;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <form className='column player'>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='text'
          id='username'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.username}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <input
          type='password'
          id='password'
          className='input-light'
          placeholder={lang.password}
          autoComplete='off'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row player-inputs'>
        <button
          className='btn dark-btn'
          type='submit'
        >
          {lang.login}
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  repos: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedLanguage: 'EU',
      repos: null,
      error: null
    }

    this.updateLanguage = this.updateLanguage.bind(this)
    this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage)
  }
  updateLanguage (selectedLanguage) {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage,
      error: null,
      repos: null
    })

    fetchPopularRepos(selectedLanguage)
      .then((repos) => this.setState({
          repos,
          error: null,
      }))
      .catch(() => {
        console.warn('Error fetching repos: ', error)

        this.setState({
          error: 'There was an error fetching the repositories.'
        })
      })
  }
  isLoading() {
    return this.state.repos === null && this.state.error === null
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedLanguage, repos, error } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <LanguagesNav
          selected={selectedLanguage}
          onUpdateLanguage={this.updateLanguage}
        />

        {this.isLoading() && <p>LOADING...</p>}

        {error && <p>{error}</p>}

        {repos && <LoginForm repos={repos} selectedLanguage={selectedLanguage} />}

      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```